# Using Flask to format results page

Tags: python, css, html, python-3.x, flask

I am a beginner to python and flask. I have this simple app(container filler) written in python and it takes in a number as an input(teaspoons) and returns a list of tuples.

So far I have been able use flask to properly format the initial form to display 'nicely' using some html and css. When a number is put in and you submit, it just displays a list of tuples plainly. The flask code looks like this:

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template

from container_filler import ContainerFiller

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def form():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/submit', methods=['POST'])
def submit():    
    return str(ContainerFiller().calculate(int(request.form['teaspoons'])))
```

What I want to do now is based on the str returned, I want to change the background color and maybe add icons.

For example, if the  return value is [('gallon', 42)] I want to have the gallon be represented by a whole page filled with a blue color. I have been looking at tutorials and other people's code on how they typically use flask and I am not able to translate that into my code. So far, I have tried something like this but to no effect:

flask code:

```
@app.route('/submit', methods=['POST']
def submit():
    a = str(ContainerFiller().calculate(int(request.form['teaspoons'])))
    for c,d in a:
       if c == 'gallon':
          return render_template('some.html')
       else:
          return a
```

But this just gives me an 'internal server error' so it makes me think this is not a legitimate way. But I am not sure how to proceed at all.

*EDIT

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_arg
  File "/home/James/Documents/Container/service.py", line 17, in submit
for c, d in a:
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

Comment: An internal server error should dump an error traceback to the console. Please add that to the question!

Comment: @KlausD. I have added the error traceback . I didn't think my code logic was functional at all so it didn't occur to me to add this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your method `ContainerFiller().calculate` returns a tuple you have to render a template with the tuple as a parameter.

like this

```
@app.route('/submit', methods=['POST']
def submit():
    a = str(ContainerFiller().calculate(int(request.form['teaspoons'])))
    return render_template('some.html', value=a )
```

and use the value in the template engine with [jinja](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/) and change the style according to the value of a!

so basically in your some.html, you should have this :

```
<div>
This is a text inside a div element.
We are still in the div element.
</div>
```

and change the syle according to the value of c :

```
<style>
div {

{% for c, d in value %}
        {% if c == 'gallon' %}
        background-color: lightblue;
        {% elif c == 'avalue' %}
        background-color: red ;
        {% else %}
        background-color: green;
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}

}
```